# How to make button go back to specified view controller

Tags: ios, uitabbar

I have a settings page that has a configure button for one of the settings. I have them linked to where I get to the configure page, I also made a back button that brings me back to the page. But instead it brings me back to the first tab. I want it to bring me to the third. If i connect the button to the third tab view it doesn't work and the view is reformatted. Also when i go back the tabs, the selected tabs don't go with there selected image, but instead the default highlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your viewControllers are managed by a UINavigationController you can use the method

`[self.navigationController popToViewController:vc animated:YES]`

provided you have a reference to the viewController that you'd like to go `back` to. Related methods are

`[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]`
`[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]`

All documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

**Edit:** Adding comment text to answer for completeness and search purposes. If you're using a UITabBarController to manage a set of, for example, two viewControllers. And one of those viewControllers can push another viewController on top of it then you want something like this: Your tabBarController would contain two things: one viewController and one navigationController (that contains settingsViewController and configurationViewController).

Comment: Please post more information about your view hierarchy. If you're using a tabbarcontroller to manage a set of, for example, two viewControllers. And one of those viewcontrollers can push another viewcontroller on top of it then you want that viewcontroller to to actually be a navigationController that holds your original viewController plus the configurationViewController that's pushed on top of it. So your tabBarController would contain two things: one viewController and one navigationController (that contains settingsViewController and configurationViewController).